# CSS Modules don't return class

Tags: reactjs, css-modules, custom-react-scripts

I would like to install css modules into `create-react-app` and I came across this https://github.com/kitze/custom-react-scripts.

After setting things up, I created a test `style.module.css` file in my folder and import it with `import styles from './style.module.css';` like so,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './style.module.css';

console.log(styles); //returns '/static/media/style.module.b3708639.css'
console.log(styles.red); //returns 'undefined'

export default class Form extends Component {
    render = () => {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <TextInput />
                <PasswordInput />
                <Submit />
                <p className={[styles.red, 'test'].join(' ')}>Test</p> //rendered <p class="test">Test</p>
            </form>
        );
    }

    handleSubmit = () => {
        console.log('submit!');
    } 
}
```

This is my style.module.css content

```
.facebook_button { margin-top:10px; }
.red { color:red; }
```

Any advise?

Comment: CSS can't be printed out using JS like that.  Instead, create an html element something like: `<h1 class="red">This should be red</h1>`

Comment: I'm using react from create-react-app with custom-react-scripts fork, trying to use CSS-modules with my components. You are referring to the traditional css html input. Perhaps I should edit my question with code to be more explicit.

Comment: Might be trivial to ask, but did you check that you have `REACT_APP_CSS_MODULES=true`?

Comment: Yeap, i have `REACT_APP_CSS_MODULES = true;` and `REACT_APP_CSS_MODULE_CLASSNAME_TEMPLATE = 'module-[sha512:hash:base32]-[name]-[local]';`

Comment: Well, that's perfect and I am trying it right now and I have it displaying perfectly red the Test text. Could it be your // rendered comment is not helping? Try wrapping it with curly braces?

Comment: Wait, also your class for the Test <p> element should be className.

Comment: Oh i added the rendered comment specifically here, its not in my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168389/discussion-between-ntp-and-claireckc).

Answer (score 1):

Installing the `custom-react-scripts` as a scripts-version from the beginning should do.

Like this:

`create-react-app my-app --scripts-version custom-react-scripts`

Otherwise, if installing after using CRA itself on the same app, it will give it the `/static/media/` route to static files, which won't give you the styles object you expect in the files where you import it.